# How exactly does fleming s right hand rule help in determining the direction of the induced emf in a coil

Tags: electromagnetism

The direction of induced emf in a coil can always be determined using the Lenz law.. using the opposite polarity concept.. but how exactly does a right hand rule help here in this case. A north pole of a magnet is brought closer to the coil. How do u determine the direction of the emf in the coil using Fleming s right hand rule?

Comment: Faradays law says emf is evaluated anti clockwise, the surface da element points out of the page. From there, determining the sign of the -db/dt can show if negative of positive work is done anticlockwise. If its negative,  negative work is done anticlockwise meaning positive work is done clockwise, so current is clockwise

Answer (score 0):

The thumb points the direction of motion of conductor in the magnetic or relative to magnetic field. The rest you already know.

You would be facing problem to determine direction of motion of conductor. Its direction is relative to magnetic field. You can choose a strength of magnetic field and assume that it is the refrence point. Now the direction of motion of conductors relative to that point is your required direction.

For example if there is a coil with a magnet on its right side with north pole towards coil. Now as you push magnet towards left, You can see that the coil moves towards right relative to any given strength of field. You will assume your field line to be static.

The current would be anti-clockwise as seen from magnet.